# How to write a java regular expression to identify java functions?

Tags: java, regex

I want to identify the java methods, just like string `public native void TextTransArgs(int i, boolean flag, String s)`. Also, I want to extract the method name, type, return-type and the args-list type(s).So how to write the regular expression?

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(public|private|protected).*(?<=\\()[^\\)]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("public native void TextTransArgs(int i, boolean flag, String s)");
    if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: (?:(?:public)|(?:private)|(?:static)|(?:protected)\s+)*

Comment: A regex for that? You had better use a grammar engine... Also, what says that all components will be on the same line?

Comment: Balanced `<>` for generics are not regular.

Comment: You can indeed only do it if the code is correctly indented and formed, (i.e. all the function declarations are at the same indentation level and are in one line)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this with a regular expression.  You're going to need some really beefy parsing to happen if you want to be able to correctly match all legitimate methods.

Comment: Yeah,the function description is formed by decompilation.So the grammer is the same,and the function description is on the same line.

Comment: You also have the problem that, for instance, `public static native` or `native public static` or other combinations are all equally valid Java. Really, use a dedicated grammar engine (grappa, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

this is known as defining grammar, its better to use any grammar like ANTLR. i'ld recommend to see the ANTLR structure first.OR first define a class based on Lexical analysis structure. HTH

Comment: Yeah,the function description is formed by decompilation.So the grammer is the same,and the function description is on the same line

Comment: ok try one more thing that is like lexical analysis. define your own lexemes and then form a structure by combination of those lexemes then match that lexeme str with your methods. i think you are working on coverage analysis of prog/code. it is achievable and i've done this

Comment: @user2301210 The information about decompilation should appear in your question.